# Algum dicionário IPA de inglês americano?

Tags: dicionário

Quero me referir a um arquivo-texto no formato:

A=[ə]

A(1)=['eɪ]

A'S=['eɪz]

A.=['eɪ]

A.'S=['eɪz]

A.S=['eɪz]

A42128=['eɪf'ɔrt'uw'ʌnt'u'eɪt]

AAA=[trˌɪpəɫ'eɪ]

AABERG=['ɑbɝg]

AACHEN=['ɑkən]

AACHENER=['ɑkənɝ]

AAKER=['ɑkɝ]

AALSETH=['ɑɫsɛθ]

AAMODT=['ɑmət]

Comment: O quê isso tem a ver com Delphi/Lazarus?

Comment: Votei para fechar como fora do escopo. Não me parece ser um problema de programação.

Comment: Isto é um "pedido/sugestão" de API para trabalhar com dicionário (principalmente baseadas em opiniões)?

Answer (score 2):

O [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) costuma ter IPA nas definições; você pode baixar o pacote com o [dump de julho de 2015](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/20150602/enwiktionary-20150602-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2) (todos os dumps estão [aqui](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/)), mas você vai precisar processar o .xml pra extrair o dado no formato que você quer.